# Auction site with Django

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

If one is to build an online auction site using Django, then would it be a good idea to modify an existing CMS? If so, could someone suggest a CMS for the scaffolding?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could starting building with [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) which is a great CMS that is very much aimed at extensibility. It has a plugin architecture which allows you to integrate your existing (or third party) apps.

If you are making an auction site though, it mightn't so much be a CMS you are after as much as a app-platform for builing off. So i'd recommend that you have a look at [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) which is a project that allows you to start your own project with a lot of the common requirements of web apps already satisfied (like profiles, email auth, social authentication, commenting etc.)

Comment: Does Pinax have apps for e-commerce/transactions?

Comment: Pinax doesn't really 'have' apps, instead it just harnesses a lot of the popular apps that are around today. I don't think it deals with ecommerce. Django-CMS on the other hand has a sister project that they are working on at the moment called django-shop. After that, there is also a mature project called django-satchmo aimed at django ecommerce. The beauty of using django-cms or pinax is that you can go on to incorporate whatever feature you need for your project.

Comment: Thanks. How about Satchmo? Is it easily extensible to handle auction and other functions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Pinax instead of customizing an existing CMS according to your needs.If you want more choices then there's also a project called [Satchless](http://satchless.com/)